# Access Active::Record relations from other relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In rails 4, have a model like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups                                                                                                       
  has_many :contents, through: :groups                                                                                                       
  has_many :content_masks
  has_many(
    :hidden_contents,
    through: :content_masks,
    source: :content,
    class_name: "Content"
  )
  has_many(
    :visible_contents,
    ->{ where("contents.id NOT IN (#{hidden_contents.select('contents.id').to_sql})") },
    through: :groups,
    class_name: "Content"
  )
end
```

I can't, however, access the `hidden_contents` relation from the `visible_contents` relation. Is this possible?

It seems like the relation is called on a specific instance, and I should be able to access it somehow, right?

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see some sample code, but assuming you're trying to do something like `User.visible_contents.hidden_contents` you're going to get some sort of error. This is because `visible_contents` returns an AR Relation, which does not contain any of the model-defined relationships (so no, in the strictest sense of answering your question, you can't do this).

You would, however, be able to get away with something like this: `User.visibile_contents.first.hidden_contents` or `User.visible_contents.map(&:hidden_contents)`. Kind of hard to answer the question accurately without knowing exactly what you're trying to do.